# Midpoint justification of lines in Xcode 8; Extension?

Tags: swift, formatting, xcode8

I'm not sure anyone else would have this bizarre desire, which is to say I realise this is probably an unusual request.

I'd like to take what's in the top example, and have it automagically become "centre justified" on the divisor, the ":" character.

Is this something an Xcode extension could be programmed to do?

[image]

Here's a simple example of a context in which this would be desirable (to me), but consider that many use cases involve much more diverse use of many more actions, and complex use of sequences and groupings of actions, too.

[image]

Comment: Might be a person preference, but it seems like a bad idea to have your CGPoint initializers at the same indentation level. They should either be in one line, or further indented.

Comment: I'm chuckling when I say this: "There's a LOT of bad ideas here!", but for the sake of rapid reading, and the fact that I have dozens of these to make some complex animations, I've found this format to be the most readable, for rapid visual scanning, identity and to then "jump into and edit" where necessary. I know, there's probably a lot of things about this that are wrongheaded, but it works, for me, in the massive trial-and-error editing I'm doing to get the timing, order and curves of these animations just-so.

Comment: The problem, it's a time consuming effort to actually layout code like this, involving spacing and tabbing and backspacing and spacing etc... very annoying process, but gives me that speed of editing the numbers and settings that matter, and ability to see which is which, and doing what, real quick.

Comment: Have you considered using an initializer or constructor that either sets parameters that are always the same or has default params for the most common use case? Most of the time my function calls get gross like this there's a solution a level or two up.

Comment: Anyway; whatever works for you, works for you! I don't know of an Xcode extension that would do you want, but if you're dealing with a couple of the same functions all the time adding a completion shortcut might get you what you need.

Comment: "Have you considered using an initializer or constructor that either sets parameters that are always the same or has default params for the most common use case? Most of the time my function calls get gross like this there's a solution a level or two up." I'm completely to newb to understand what this means.

Comment: This might be getting to complicated and I don't know what API this is, but one example is if your easeFunction/type are always the same you could make a function in the class that creates a move function and only take the time, from, and to, and then calls the original function with the settings you always use.

Comment: That's the problem, none of these are the same, and I'm constantly changing their values, and types, to get the 'feel' right. Like using code as a visual editor, of sorts. Hence the desire for this layout.

Comment: Have a look at the example extension in [WWDC2016 Session 414](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/414/), starting around 27-28 minutes. You could possibly implement a similar `XCSourceEditorCommand` that (instead of replacing `UIColor`/`UIImage` literals) sets the indentation for lines containing `:` (in, say, selected text) to one such that all lines in the selection have their first `:` symbol aligned (with the longest argument name, e.g. `easeFunction` above), by, while processing the lines in the buffer, replacing `:` lines with copied lines with some additional space chars.

Comment: Are your animations all `SKEase.move` with a different set of parameters?

Comment: No, some are SKActions that wait, some are SKActions that do motion animation, others are sound instigators, etc etc. Kind of like a complex AE timeline, but with Actions, many of which have custom timing functions, some have completion blocks... there's a lot.

Comment: @Wain I've just picked one example, one without completion blocks or other complex or obscure activities to show the justification desire.

Comment: And please excuse my peculiar line returns. They work for me, as this permits much faster editing of values, for me.

Comment: So the comment from dfri is likely your best option, I don't expect you'll find an existing formatter like that as it's a weird layout...

Comment: Yes, I agree @Wain. I don't expect to find an existing formatter. And, at the time of asking the question, knew nothing about formatting focused extensions, or their capabilities. Some of that has changed, largely thanks to his comment.

Comment: I've also been using Sublime 3, and it's ability to have 8 panels of code open at the same time, so as to have 8 insights into different actions and their settings onscreen at the same time. Nextup... I'll probably make some kind of visual editor for these things, but that's a ways off from my programming prowess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's possible. Take a look at this [extension on Github called Alignment](https://github.com/tid-kijyun/XcodeSourceEditorExtension-Alignment), which is aligning assignments.

With some little modifications that should get you there.